# Will LinkedIn company updates be available to users who are not admins of the page?

Tags: linkedin-api

Our app involves users to sign up using LinkedIn and add company pages to measure engagements.Till now any user can add any company page even if he is not a admin of it.

After the new LinkedIn Developer updates, will company updates be available to users who are not admin of the company page?

If not, what will be solution to access the updates and measure the engagement on the updates?

Which partner program should we subscribe to get LinkedIn company updates?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic becauset's a question for LinkedIn customer support, not StackOverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/linkedin/info

Comment: Hi @GaneshSittampalam. I did post it to LinkedIn customer support. They are asking me to post here. Can you remove your vote?

Comment: As the tag wiki page explains, even if Linkedin sent you here, they can't decide what's on-topic for StackOverflow. If they won't support you, that's a problem between you and them, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I've chatted with a few people from LinkedIn and the answer is no. You will not be able to access the company resource without the particular auth'd LinkedIn Account having admin access that company page.

I unfortunately do not have an easy answer for you regarding the partner program, there are many.